# creating a login controller in MVC project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

So I am creating a web application with ASP.NET MVC4 in framework 4.5. I wish to add an account system. I have created a database with users and roles and now need to connect that with my web app.

I have used the visual studio tool for adding ADO.NET Entity Data Model, and have connected to my database, selected all the tables and clicked generate. I got classes for the user and group tables, as well as a class for `database.context`(not sure what this is). After the wizard created the class files, I went out to find a way to protect the users (password encryption and user validation) and came across [this](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm?=rd#aspsourcecode) web article. I created the class inside the models folder.

Now its on to the controller, and here lies the problem. When i look at the source for the template project that has web login integrated into the template i only get confused.  the methods in the login controler always have the `returnurl` parameter and i have no idea where that comes from. Also it uses the `WebSecurity.Login()` method to login and i am wondering how to make my web app use the methods that i have referenced before.

Ofc, if  there is a simpler way to do this without letting VS auto generate a lot of code that i don't know what to do with, it is preferable to use that instead, I don't want to have code that's not useful to the app if i don't need to.

The database itself is custom, that is to say the tables that are autogenerated by the internet application template are not suitable for my needs. most of the tutorials i found on the web, includint the one in the comments is working with the build in entity framework database with the userProfile table and membership table. Is there maybe a way i can adjust this, so  that the tables created have a different structure? If that approach is better ofc.

UPDATE:
So i got to this point in the code. i have created a users controller with the following methods:

```
internal bool UserExists(LoginModel model)
private void CheckIfFirstDeploy()
private void RegisterFirstAdmin()
private void registerUser(string ALPHA_ADMIN_USERNAME, string ALPHA_ADMIN_PASSWORD, Group group)
internal bool PasswordValid(LoginModel model)
```

the account controller (that is another class and file), instances the users controller and runs like for authentication:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    UsersController uc = new UsersController();
    if (ModelState.IsValid && uc.UserExists(model) && uc.PasswordValid(model))
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, false);
        return View("Dashboard");
    }
    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
    return View(model);
}
```

When the app notices that there's no entries for users it runs the `CheckIfFirstDeploy()` function, fills the groups table with the first 3 roles and creates the first admin user as presented below:

```
private void RegisterFirstAdmin(){
    const string ALPHA_ADMIN_USERNAME = "username";
    const string ALPHA_ADMIN_PASSWORD = "password";

    if (db.Groups.Count() == 0)
    {
        db.Groups.Add(new Groups()
        {
            GroupName = "Administrator"
        });
        db.Groups.Add(new Groups()
        {
            GroupName = "Manager"
        });
        db.Groups.Add(new Groups()
        {
            GroupName = "User"
        });
    }

    registerUser(ALPHA_ADMIN_USERNAME, 
                 ALPHA_ADMIN_PASSWORD, 
                 Group.Administrator);


}

private void registerUser(string ALPHA_ADMIN_USERNAME, 
                          string ALPHA_ADMIN_PASSWORD, 
                          Group group) {

    db.Users
        .Add(
            new Users() { 
                Email = ALPHA_ADMIN_USERNAME,
                Hash = Crypto.PasswordHash.CreateHash(ALPHA_ADMIN_PASSWORD),
                GroupId = 1
            }
        );
}
```

When i run the app i come into a few problems. First, it seems that the database doesn't get filled with the groups that i have intended to insert, and second at the point where i have 
`if (db.Users.Count(u => u.Email == model.UserName) != 1)`

I get the following error:

`The data types text and varchar are incompatible in the equal to operator.`

The types in the database are text and in the code its defined as string.

Comment: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/security/authenticating-users-with-forms-authentication-cs

Comment: Why do you assume VS generates "trash code"? I'm pretty sure that that code has been tested very well and will probably meet your needs. It'll probably save you some time as well. If you want a robust and flexible authentication system, you should have a look at the new Identity tools: http://www.asp.net/identity

Comment: i may have been using the wrong term. what i wanted to say is  that i don't feel comfortable using code I'm not familiar with.

Comment: added additional clarification to the post

Comment: If you're not familiar with it, why not familiarize? .NET is extremely well documented, and the fact that MVC is a relatively new framework makes it that much easier to use.

Comment: @Kenneth: though i generally agree about the framework, the PoC put out my MS is generally just a quick'n'dirty last addition to get people excited about the technologies. (not as many people would jump on Identity if they didn't have a template thrust the technology upon them in their initial project). That's not to say it's horrible, but it's generally not coded well enough to remain as-is through release to production. Inevitably there's some tweaking that needs to be performed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so my problems were connected to the fact that I have created columns with the type text, so the string input (that gets transformed to varchar) cannot get compared to a text. I changed my database and now have no problems. The changes to the database happened once I used the `db.SaveChanges()` method, duh :).